# Storing an array in MySQL, while checking for existing entries

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have a database table set out like this

**test**

```
UID       | thing_id | thing
120151021 |  0000001 | some text here
```

UID, thing_id are both primary keys. thing_id has 'UNSIGNED_ZEROFILL' attribute.

With the following database trigger

```
 CREATE TRIGGER `Things_BEFORE_INSERT` BEFORE INSERT ON `things`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
 SET NEW.thing_id=IFNULL((SELECT MAX(thing_id)+1 FROM test.Things WHERE UID=NEW.UID),1); -- If NULL set it to 1 as first thing_id for this UID
 END
```

This ensures whenever a new entry is created in **thing**  it will increase **thing_id** by 1.

The problem lies with trying to insert an array of data and replacing entries at a duplicate position. Currently I've been using

```
$sql="INSERT INTO test.Things(UID,thing) VALUES (:uid,:thing1),(:uid,:thing2),(:uid,:thing3)";

$q = $dbh->prepare($sql);

$q->bindParam(':uid', $uid, PDO::PARAM_INT, 100);
$q->bindParam(':thing1', $thing1, PDO::PARAM_STR, 100);
$q->bindParam(':thing2', $thing2, PDO::PARAM_STR, 100);
$q->bindParam(':thing3', $thing3, PDO::PARAM_STR, 100);
$q->bindParam(':date', $date, PDO::PARAM_STR, 100);

//Execute
if (!$q->execute()) {
    //Spit out any errors
    echo "\nPDO::errorInfo():\n";
    print_r($dbh->errorInfo());
} else {
    echo "\nDone\n";
}
```

To statically add entries, but I want to be able to do this with an array of entries. Furthermore I need to check the position in the array and see if it is a duplicate thing_id.

For example. if I have the following in the table

```
UID       | thing_id | thing
120151021 |  0000001 | An entry here
120151021 |  0000002 | Another entry here
120151021 |  0000003 | Third entry here
```

and the following array with 4 entries

```
$entries[] = Array ( [0] => Entry1 [1] => Entry2 [2] => Entry3 [3] => Entry4 )
```

The SQL statement will check what **thing_ids** exist, replace thing 1,2,3, and create a new row with Entry4

But I have almost no idea where to start. I imagine I'll also have to pragmatically '**bindParam**' each entry too before the SQL.

Comment: Why are you using that trigger instead of the built-in `AUTO_INCREMENT` attribute?

Comment: If you want to update a row if it already exists, use the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` clause in `INSERT`.

Comment: As Barmar says, try this query  `INSERT INTO test.Things(UID,thing) VALUES (:uid,:thing1),(:uid,:thing2),(:uid,:thing3) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE thing = VALUES(thing)`

Comment: The duplicate I need to check is thing_id. So if array [0] exists, this would be a duplicate for thing_id 0000001, which would then replace 'thing' with array[0]'s contents.